# Using IManagedAddin in VC++ to load VSTO VBA add-ins

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin

I was given a VSTO Outlook add-in written in VBA, and have been tasked to reduce the start-up time. I'm rather new to the whole add-in and COM objects thing so I need some help.

The add-in takes anywhere from 0.2s to 2.0s to startup, and Outlook disables the plugin if the average startup time is >1000ms. Using the registry hack to force enable the add-in is unfortunately not an option. I've also tested it with an empty add-in, which also can take up to 1.8s to startup. I've searched SO and other such sites for a solution, and across one involving writing a "stub" in an un-managed language such as Delphi or C++, which does nothing but load the actual add-in. The interface that's supposed to do this is [IManagedAddin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/imanagedaddin-interface?view=vs-2019).

My issue is with implementing this interface. I've created a simple add-in in VC++ The class that implements `_IDTExtensibility2` is in `Connect.h`, shown below. However, I don't have a clue how to implement `IManagedAddin::Load` to load my add-in into Outlook, and there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on this. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Updated code below

```cpp
// Connect.h : Declaration of the CConnect

#pragma once
#include "resource.h"       // main symbols
#include "NativeAddin_i.h"
#include "IManagedAddin.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>



#if defined(_WIN32_WCE) && !defined(_CE_DCOM) && !defined(_CE_ALLOW_SINGLE_THREADED_OBJECTS_IN_MTA)
#error "Single-threaded COM objects are not properly supported on Windows CE platform, such as the Windows Mobile platforms that do not include full DCOM support. Define _CE_ALLOW_SINGLE_THREADED_OBJECTS_IN_MTA to force ATL to support creating single-thread COM object's and allow use of it's single-threaded COM object implementations. The threading model in your rgs file was set to 'Free' as that is the only threading model supported in non DCOM Windows CE platforms."
#endif

using namespace ATL;

// CConnect

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CConnect :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CConnect, &CLSID_Connect>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IConnect, &IID_IConnect, &LIBID_PixelLLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public IDispatchImpl<_IDTExtensibility2, &__uuidof(_IDTExtensibility2), &LIBID_AddInDesignerObjects, /* wMajor = */ 1, /* wMinor = */ 0>
{
public:
    static Outlook::_Application* outlookApp;
    static ext_ConnectMode connectMode;
    static LPDISPATCH addInInst;
    static SAFEARRAY** customArr;
    static UINT_PTR timerId;

    CConnect()
    {
    }

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(106)


BEGIN_COM_MAP(CConnect)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IConnect)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY2(IDispatch, _IDTExtensibility2)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(_IDTExtensibility2)
END_COM_MAP()



    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    void FinalRelease()
    {
    }

    static VOID CALLBACK TimerCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
    {
        KillTimer(NULL, timerId);

        HRESULT hr;
        BSTR manifestUrl = SysAllocString(L"file://path/to/manifest.vsto");

        // load add-in
        IID clsid;
        hr = IIDFromString(OLESTR("{99D651D7-5F7C-470E-8A3B-774D5D9536AC}"), &clsid); // VSTOAddinLoader CLSID

        IID iid;
        hr = IIDFromString(OLESTR("{B9CEAB65-331C-4713-8410-DDDAF8EC191A}"), &iid);
        IManagedAddin* loader;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, iid, (void**)&loader);

        hr = loader->Load(manifestUrl, outlookApp);

        _IDTExtensibility2* ext;
        hr = loader->QueryInterface(IID__IDTExtensibility2, (void**)&ext);

        hr = ext->OnConnection(outlookApp, connectMode, addInInst, customArr);

        MSO::IRibbonExtensibility* ribbon;
        hr = (???)->QueryInterface(MSO::IID_IRibbonExtensibility, (void**)&ribbon);
    }


    STDMETHOD(OnConnection)(LPDISPATCH App, ext_ConnectMode ConnectMode, LPDISPATCH AddInInst, SAFEARRAY * * custom)
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        UINT time = 200;

        Outlook::_Application* app;
        hr = App->QueryInterface(__uuidof(Outlook::_Application), (void**)&app);

        // init static members
        outlookApp = app;
        connectMode = ConnectMode;
        addInInst = AddInInst;
        customArr = custom;

        timerId = SetTimer(NULL, 0, time, (TIMERPROC)&TimerCallback);
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHOD(OnDisconnection)(ext_DisconnectMode RemoveMode, SAFEARRAY * * custom)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHOD(OnAddInsUpdate)(SAFEARRAY * * custom)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHOD(OnStartupComplete)(SAFEARRAY * * custom)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHOD(OnBeginShutdown)(SAFEARRAY * * custom)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }
};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(Connect), CConnect)
Outlook::_Application* CConnect::outlookApp = NULL;
ext_ConnectMode CConnect::connectMode = ext_cm_AfterStartup;
LPDISPATCH CConnect::addInInst = NULL;
SAFEARRAY** CConnect::customArr = NULL;

UINT_PTR CConnect::timerId = 0;
```

```cpp
// IManagedAddin.h
#pragma once
#include "resource.h"
#include "NativeAddin_i.h"

struct __declspec(uuid("B9CEAB65-331C-4713-8410-DDDAF8EC191A"))
IManagedAddin : IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual STDMETHOD(Load)(BSTR bstrManifestUrl, LPDISPATCH pdisApplication) = 0;
    virtual STDMETHOD(Unload)() = 0;
};
```

```
// pch.h
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

// add headers that you want to pre-compile here
#include "framework.h"

#import "libid:AC0714F2-3D04-11D1-AE7D-00A0C90F26F4" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, named_guids, auto_search, no_namespace
#import "libid:2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, named_guids, auto_search, rename_namespace("MSO")
#import "libid:00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, named_guids, auto_search, rename_namespace("Outlook")

#endif //PCH_H
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to wait until `OnConnection` callback fired and started a timer - you might be able to use a separate thread, but in my case the processing had to be done on the main thread due to some functionality that had thread affinity. `OnConnection` will give you `Outlook.Application` object.

In the timer callback (Outlook is not looking), create an instance of the `IManagedAddin` COM object using `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_IManagedAddin, ...)`. Call `IManagedAddin::Load`. The path must be in the form `file://c:/the/folder/myaddin.vsto`.

QI the `IManagedAddin` object for `IDTExtensibility2` interface and call `IDTExtensibility2::OnConnection()` using the parameters saved from the native `OnConnection` callback.

If Outlook has already called your C++ implementation of `OnStartupComplete`, call `OnStartupComplete` on the VSTO addin. If not, you can do it later.

QI for `IRibbonExtensibility` and call `IRibbonExtensibility::GetCustomUI`. Or you can hardcode the ribbon XML in the C++ addin. Note that if Outlook calls `IRibbonExtensibility::GetCustomUI` on your C++ addin, and you have to delegate the call to the VSTO addin before you had a chance to run your timer code, you have no choice but to call the above code immediately rather than in a timer callback since `GetCustomUI` cannot be postponed.

If you are using task panes (i.e. `ICustomTaskPaneConsumer` interface is implemented by your VSTO addin), your C++ addin must also implement it (besides the `IDTExtensibility2` and `ICustomTaskPaneConsumer` interfaces). QI `IManagedAddin` for `IServiceProvider` interface and use it to call `IServiceProvider::QueryService(GUID_NULL, IID_ICustomTaskPaneConsumer, ...)`. then call `ICustomTaskPaneConsumer.CTPFactoryAvailable` - note that `ICustomTaskPaneConsumer` does not come from your VSTO addin's `IDTExtensibility2` interface but rather though the `IServiceProvider` object off the `IManagedAddin` interface.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I still can't seem to get the add-in to load. I'm getting `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE2D97B8BD (Mso20win32client.dll) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.` when calling `loader->Load(manifestUrl, app)` (code above is updated). The debugger can't load symbols in `VSTOLoader.dll` so I can't step through it either. I suspect that I'm passing the wrong application object.

Comment: Where does outlookApplication come from?

Comment: Also, try to QI it for Outlook.Application instead f just a generic IDispatch.

Comment: Okay, I think I've managed to load the `.vsto` file. In your third paragraph you've mentioned to QI the "returned object" for `IDTExtensibility`, where should this object come from? `Load` doesn't return any objects..

Comment: Yes, sorry, you need to QI for IDTExtensibility the IManagedAddin object after calling Load.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far, think I'm close to the solution. I'm supposed to call `IDTExtensibility2::OnConnection()` on the QI'd `IManagedAddin` object using the parameters of the native add-in `OnConnection` right? It seems a bit counter-intuitive. Also, which object should I QI for `IRibbonExtensibility`? Both the `IManagedAddin` and `IDTExtensibility2` object return `E_NOINTERFACE`. Again, thanks for helping this COM newbie!

Comment: I QI `IDTExtensibility2` for `IRibbonExtensibility`. Does you VB.Net addin implement any ribbon functionality?